# React setState not updating state and UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I try to clear ingredient when users click purchasing cancel, and  set state purchasing false then ingredient clean, but state seems to be true. and doesn't clear ingredient from orders with realtime, even modal window cl what should i need to do ?

```
    ///Root Component

            state = {
                    purchasing: false
                }
                purchaseCancleHandler = () => {
            this.setState({purchasing: false
            });
              }
    <OrderSummary
purchaseContinue = {
                    this.purchaseContinuewHandler
                }
                purchaseCancle = {
                    this.purchaseCancleHandler
                } 
/>

//Child component    

     import React, {Component} from 'react'

    import Button from '../../UI/Button/Button'
    import Aux from '../../../hoc/Aux'


        class OrderSummary extends Component {

            componentWillUpdate() {
        //console.log('[OrderSummer] willupdate')

            }
            render ()
            {

                const ingredientSummary =Object.keys(this.props.ingredients)
                .map(igkey => {
                    return <li key={igkey}><span style={{textTransform:'capitalize'}}>{igkey}</span>: {this.props.ingredients[igkey]}</li>

                });


            return(
                <Aux>
                <h3>Your Order</h3>
        <p> A delicious Burger with the following ingredient</p>
        <ul>
        {ingredientSummary}
        </ul>
        <p>Total Price :<strong>{this.props.totalprice.toFixed(2)}</strong></p>
        <p>Continure To Checkout ?</p>
        <Button btnType="Danger" clicked={this.props.purchaseCancle}>CANCEL</Button>
        <Button btnType="Success" clicked={this.props.purchaseContinue}>CONTINUE</Button>
        </Aux>

            );
        }
        }

        export default OrderSummary;
```

Comment: Please add log inside the purchaseCancleHandler  method to check its called or not

Comment: Can you provide the actual code please? what you've provided tells us nothing except that it isn't valid code

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the whole component's code. Also, you tagged your question with *react-redux* – how exactly are you using Redux?

Comment: do you mean add console log ?  , i have did that already

Comment: @PatrickHund  sorry it was my mistake to added tag react-redux, it should only react, however could you see my problem Screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
        purchasing: false
    }
    purchaseCancleHandler = () => {
this.setState({purchasing: false
});
  }

 <Button btnType="Danger" clicked={this.purchaseCancleHandler}>CANCEL</Button>
```

You don't need .props if it's declare in the same local state. Also, your function wasn't invoked spelled correctly (it was missing "Handler")

Comment: it's not same local state , i want to pass as props property "purchaseCancle " that's why i didn't use "Handler " on props child component , example :  passed,   purchaseCancle = {
                    this.purchaseCancleHandler
                }     Recieved on order summery component like this way : <Button btnType="Danger" clicked={this.props.purchaseCancle}>CANCEL</Button>

Comment: Did you mean to use "clicked" instead of "onClick" <Button btnType="Danger" onClick={() => this.props.purchaseCancle()}>CANCEL</Button>

Comment: yes I have used custom Button like this <button onClick ={props.clicked>{props.children}</button>  , i have passed as props propert "clicked" from root component

Comment: Okay, to clear the modal value you need to do something like clearModal = () => {this.setState({salad:'', bacon:'', cheese:'', meat:''})} then pass that in to the clear button

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to call a method defined on the component itself, not a prop passed to the component, so you need to use `this.purchaseCancleHandler`.

```
state = {
    purchasing: false
}
purchaseCancleHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
        purchasing: false
    });
}

<Button btnType="Danger" clicked={this.purchaseCancleHandler}>CANCEL</Button>
```

Comment: Please could you see my whole project code on  github child component  [link](https://github.com/IMiraz/FullStack-MyBurger-React.Redux/blob/master/src/components/Burger/OrderSummary/OrderSummary.js)  my Root Componet  [link](https://github.com/IMiraz/FullStack-MyBurger-React.Redux/blob/master/src/containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    purchasing: null
  }
}


purchaseCancleHandler = () => {
  this.setState({
    purchasing: false // need set this value difference with initial value
  });
}

// Child component
clicked = () => {
  this.props.purchaseCancle()
}

<Button btnType="Danger" clicked={this.clicked}>CANCEL</Button>
```

To make sure component will render after setState, need set value for `purchasing` difference with initial value.

Comment: please check my post code again i have edited my post,  however why i should use onClick={this.purchaseCancle} i don't i wanted to handle  in root compoponet  i want to pass as a props property in the child orderSummary component,

Comment: did you use custom Button component ? because normal Button just can handle click at `onClick`. You can check my pen https://codepen.io/duongtungls/pen/zJgBNR, 1st button with clicked, 2nd button with onClick. I edited by answer, I think you should use onClick in child component to handle click

Comment: Yes i have used custom component , like this <button
     onClick ={props.clicked>{props.children}</button>

Comment: Could you test with                   `purchaseCancle = {
                    () => { this.purchaseCancleHandler() }
                }`
in root component < OrderSummary ....

Comment: I edited answer. I add more function in child component. You can test with `clicked = () => {
  this.props.purchaseCancle()
}` with `<Button btnType="Danger" clicked={this.clicked}>CANCEL</Button>`

Comment: Please could you see my whole project code on  github, Child Component [link](https://github.com/IMiraz/FullStack-MyBurger-React.Redux/blob/master/src/components/Burger/OrderSummary/OrderSummary.js)  my Root Componet  [link](https://github.com/IMiraz/FullStack-MyBurger-React.Redux/blob/master/src/containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder.js) custom Button Component  [link](https://github.com/IMiraz/FullStack-MyBurger-React.Redux/blob/master/src/components/UI/Button/Button.js)

Comment: I just test with your code, I add console.log to check `        this.setState({purchase: false}, () => {
            console.log('purchaseCancleHandler', this.state.purchase)
        });` so it still print out `purchaseCancleHandler false` . that's mean it already apply. And I see UI update